# Reseting nth-child "clear: both" when Multiple nth-child are Inherited

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am using CSS (SCSS specifically) to apply styling to the same element on different media sizes: **A**, **B**, and **C**.

I am using the following for **A**:

```
&:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

And, I am using the following for **B**:

```
&:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

And, I am using the following for **C**:

```
&:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

The styling is inherited from **A** to **B**, and from **B** to **C**. So "2n+1" is being applied to **B** and **C** when it should not, and "3n+1" is being applied to **C** when it should not.

I reset the **B** and **C** properties for "2n+1" by doing the following:

```
&:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    clear: none;
}
```

Then I reset the **C** property for "3n+1" by doing the following:

```
&:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: none;
}
```

This did not work because "2n+1" will evaluate to true for **B** and **C**, and "3n+1" will evaluate to true for **C**. So I am getting "clear: none" being applied at "2n+1" and "3n+1".

I am stuck, how do I reset or disable a selector (nth-of-type) once it is set? Or how do I remove a "clear" property once it is set in a selector?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by doing the following for **B**:

```
&:nth-of-type(2n+1),
&:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: none; // Clear previous "A" setting
}
&:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

And doing the following for **C**:

```
&:nth-of-type(2n+1),
&:nth-of-type(3n+1),
&:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    clear: none; // Clear previous "A" and "B" settings
}
&:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

This resets the "clear" on the previous selectors then applies the new one value to "clear".

I hope this helps other people that were stuck like I was.

Answer (score 0):

One way to overcome this problem, is by specifying both a min and a max value for the media queries. From A to B, from B to C, from C and above.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Fee-fi-fo-fum but I am restricted on what constrains I could apply to media selection, but I can see how your suggestion can help.